# Adding or adjusting CSS for widget and widget area in WP site

Tags: css, widget

I hope I can explain this properly. I have the home page. It has 4 widget areas on it. Each widget area has something in it (you'll see in the screen shot I'm including). Three widgets just text with crazy CSS going on and have a header w/a box around the header (including text). The 4th widget is irrelevant because it's just an image.

One widget's header has a box, radius, background color and it's left/right justified with the rest of the information inside the widget. Two other widgets - the header is not justified left and right 100% w/the entire widget area.

See the image as it'll make more sense.

here's a direct link to the image for a alrge view: http://postimage.org/image/ofdqc1sa7/

The wdiget section "New customers" - see how it's left/right justified. It stretches the entire width of the whole box. Now see the Existing and Why - how it's not stretched all the way across left and right. How can I get it to stretch all the way across? Iv'e been going over this soooo many times with change this/change that. My Firebug in Firefox is o fire, but I can't seem to get the correct CSS code to make this happen. Driving me crazy.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance for your reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this style

```
.cl-content {
    margin: 8px;
}
```

To this

```
.cl-content {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

However, this will cause some alignment problems with your columns. But, that class is what is causing your problem.

[ Edit ]

If you change the #text-17 and #text-18 widths to 670px, it should resolve your problem.

I would also change #LoginWithAjax to #LoginWithAjax { padding: 5px; }

Comment: Hey Chris.  This worked perfect.  I can adjust the columns.  That's not problem moving them left and right with code changes.  I just adjusted one piece of code and there you have it.  Thank you so much for this fix...

Answer (score 0):

Initialy I'd say there may be a padding issue.  Is there a live link that I can firebug to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Other guy got to it before me.  Thanks. =)